# Subfolder .htaccess copied RewriteRule compatibility

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to do this simple rewrite, which in itself is straightforward:

```
example.com/[home|login] => example.com/?a=[home|login]

RewriteRule ^(home|login)/?$ /?a=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**The Problem:** A development "environment" lives within `example.com/dev` and has the same content as the root directory.

In addition to the above rule, requests to `example.com/dev/[home|login]` should redirect to `example.com/dev/?a=[home|login]` *with the exact same setup in `/.htaccess` and `/dev/.htaccess`.*

Currently, `/dev` requests are being redirected to `/?a=[home|login]` instead of `/dev/?a=[home|login]`, presumably because the parent rule in `/.htaccess` is conflicting with the `/dev/.htaccess` rule.

Comment: Did you try to run the dev rule first, the other rule second?

Comment: There's just one rule - but two files. One's at the root, one in `/dev` - the same content in both `.htaccess` files.

Comment: You can add another rule to your .htacces file in your root. This one should go before the one you already have. `RewriteRule ^dev/([home|login)/?$ dev/?a=$1`. No need for .htaccess in subfolder.

Comment: ...but then the problem is that it's overridden by the shorter rule in the parent folder, which is relative to `/dev`, not `/`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I also missed your thought on the non-need in the subfolder - and I totally agree, except that's where the development version lives, which is an exact (repo) copy of what's in "prod" - so I can't just get rid of it.

Comment: When you said exact copy I thought you meant filename-wise. Try `RewriteRule ^(.+)/(home|login)/?$ $1/?a=$2 [QSA,L]`